# Bootstrap Modal how to load PHP variable

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

I would like a simple form to be loaded in a bootsrap modal. Here is a link that loads a page with php variables but I would like modal to be shown.

```
<a href=klient_aktualizacja.php?id=<?php echo $klient->id;?>class="badge badge-primary">Aktualizacja</a>
```

How to edit modal get the php variable that is above? Here is the modal first line, but how should I make it to open the modal not a page?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="?????" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="?????"
    aria-hidden="true">
```

Ia another modal that is working but it serves as add data form in a place of "?????" I have specific id. SO please feel free to replace "?????" with sth that is needed. Thank You.

Comment: Do you have one modal per client ID or do you wish to reuse the same modal window and modify records with different ids?

Comment: Yes with different ids, it means that I have a list of clients with edit button next to each name, and if I want to edit a client I want a modal to open and his data should be in a form. Each time different data.

Comment: To reuse a modal dialog to edit different records, you need to dynamically pass the record/id to the dialog. It is the easiest to achieve with JS/Ajax. Please show us the rest of the relevant code

Comment: The thing is that I have one modal working with "add client" and its ok, but in this form nothing is taken from the database and now I am trying to achieve the same effect with "edit" so the only thing I have is a link to working solution but not with a modal but with next page that opens.

Comment: If you want to reuse the same modal, you need to retrieve data by ajax. Agreed with @EriksKlotins.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it with some jQuery.

This is a link for deleting:

```
echo "<td><a rel='$comment_id' href='javascript:void(0)' class='delete_link'>DELETE</a></td>";
```

classic Bootstrap Modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
```

```
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Modal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete this ?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger modal_delete">Delete</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And some jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".delete_link").on('click', function () {

        var id = $(this).attr("rel");

        var delete_url = "comments.php?delete="+ id +" ";

        $(".modal_delete").attr("href", delete_url);

        $("#myModal").modal('show');

    })

})
```

So I used jQuery to open modal when clicked on the link and to take 'rel' attribute from it so I can use it later in modal, then targeted the specific delete button in modal and passed the url.

Comment: Sorry I have been trying hard but still don't understand it. Can You be more precise. In query You write #myModal in modal there is no id etc. What is $comment_id? Give me more hints please.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason whole Modal code didn't show

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

This is top part with id of this modal.

$comment_id is information I wanted to send to modal when opened, for reference, you would probably send $klient->id, so that modal has informations, then my delete_url  is just a get request which was in href before, before I put it in modal that is, you can probably do the same. I hope this clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

- in the tag which represents to 'Edit' store a unique value like client id which represents the client
- on clicking this element trigger an `$(ajax).post()` to get the that clients details
- on ajax success use the response data to assign values to the modal form for editing
- use `modal('show')` to display the modal with the populated form
- on modal form submit, make sure that you have passed the client id with the form data for record updation in database

---

Store client id with the tag which represents the action

```
<span onclick="edit_client(<?php echo $klient->id;?>)" class="badge badge-primary">Edit</span>
```

On clicking this element call a function passing the client id ( You could also assign the client id to a data attribute and onclick function take the client id from it )

```
<script>
function edit_client(client_id = '' ) {
    if(client_id!='') {
        // call ajax. pass client_id as data
        $(ajax).post({
            'url': '', // url to get the client details
            'data': {
                client_id: client_id,
            }
            // other necessary properties
        })
        .done( function(data) {
            // check for data status
            // assign values to form elements accordingly to the structure of response data
            $('#edit_modal #client_name').val($data['client_name']);
            // like so for other elements also ( remember about the response data structure while assigning values to form elements)

            $('#edit_modal').modal('show'); // show the edit modal which now has the client details
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ok THX but I still have some problems if You could help me, so if I delete everything from the script and leave only function, the button triggers the modal, so its ok? But what next in script I make - 'url': 'klient_aktualizacja.php', 'data': {id: id} bc in my DB its called id  #client_name=>#nazwaKlienta - and nothing happened.

Comment: by Ajax you are requesting the client details from the server side. So, in server side you should get the client data, json_encode() that data and send it as a response

Comment: the way you implement the server side methods depends on your framework. Also, I'm did not mention to delete everything from your script. That totally depends. You have to take care of that. I just wrote script tags just to be sure that the function should be in a script tag which may already have some functions defined.

Comment: @HubertKubasiewicz make sure that you are getting the data for the corresponding id that is being passed. After that, the data array should be json encoded and echo'd. For this data to be received headers must be set correctly. Header being: Content-Type application/json